# Running Multiplication in excel

Tags: excel, multiplication

I keep thinking this should be easy but the answer is evading me. I would like to transform the value in each row of a column based on another column's value. For example, assume I have Table1 as follows:

[Table Caluculation Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBpeb.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBpeb.jpg)

First cell in eff column is result of multiplication of Qty and rate and second cell is result of First value in Eff cell and 2nd value in rate column and so on. But the problem is as my product changes i need to perform same calculation for that product as well. For example in below table mif my product changes to B in table, i need to perform same calculation for that as well
Kindly help

Comment: so in the second row put `=C1*B2` and copy down? where Columcn C is the Eff and B is the rate.  In C1 `=A1*B1`

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, you are right !

Comment: @ScottCraner But the problem is as my product changes i need to perform same calculation for that product as well. For example in below table mif my product changes to B in table, i need to perform same calculation for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

In E2 put this formula:

```
=IF(B2<> B1,C2*D2,E1*D2)
```

And copy down